# Build same RubyCocoa application version for Leopard and Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, ruby-cocoa

I have RubyCocoa 0.13.2 based application. It works on 10.5.8 and earlier versions. When i try to run it on 10.6 it crashes on infinite loop. 10.6 has 0.13.2 built in, but it's not same binary as for 10.5. When i tried to build my application's Xcode 3.1.3 project with 0.13.2 framework from 10.6, it gave a link error - malformed object on 0.13.2 framework binary. The application, that is built with Xcode 3.2 doesn't run on leopard, in spite that i built only 32 Arch. configuration. My question is whether there is a way to build a version, that will run on both platforms?

Thanks,

Nava

EDIT: I feel pretty exhausted trying to solve it and the best thing would be to just rewrite everything in Cocoa, at least you can debug it in a human way. But i don't have a permission for this luxury :)

Comment: Thank you @Alex for politically correct editing :))

Comment: You should try fixing the infinite loop on 10.6 instead of trying to get a binary library to work on a different OS version (mind all those changes from 10.5 to 10.6 - especially that it's now pure 64bit).

Comment: I fixed the infinite loop on 10.6 and it's working now. The problem is that the version that is working on 10.6 doesn't work on 10.5+ and vise versa. That's what I'm asking here, how do i make SAME version for Leopard & Snow Leopard, since they are using the same RubyCocoa version...

Answer (score 0):

fat binary maybe??

Comment: What i tried so far was building for 32bit-Universal architecture only  using GCC 4.2. You suggest building 32/64bit-universal?

Answer (score 0):

I got a notification from RubyCocoa source forge team on a RubyCocoa version 1.0.1 which is supposed to work for Leopard & Snow Leopard. Will give it a chance, especially it has a fix for a ver. 1.0.0 crash on Snow Leopard

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! 
First of all there is a new RubyCocoa version (rev. 2277, based on 1.0.0, soon the release), that solved SL crash and works for both Leopard & Snow Leopard.

I built a RubyCocoa version for i386 & ppc architectures. 
In the project I set 32bit-universal. Base SDK = 10.5, Deployment target = 10.5, Compiler = GCC 4.0.

Now I have one version, that I can build on Leopard & Snow Leopard and it works on both platforms (it doesn't say, that it there are no crashes, but this is for another question)

Answer (score -1):

You should probably have the following build settings :-

- Architectures = 32/64-bit Universal
- Base SDK = Mac OS X 10.6
- Deployment Target = Mac OS X 10.5

If this doesn't work on 10.5, try changing

- Base SDK = Mac OS X 10.5

I don't think the version of GCC should matter unless you can't build successfully.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.. It immediately crashes on Leopard in RubyCocoa on oc_import.rb:84: [BUG] Bus Error. we use system ruby, which is 1.8.6 for leopard & 1.8.7 for snow leopard. Same RubyCocoa 0.13.2 for both.

Comment: Have you tried creating a really simple app and trying to get that to work on both 10.5 and 10.6. That would help narrow things down a bit.

Comment: The "fat" application works for snow leopard and crashes for leopard. The problem, I'm sure - RubyCocoa layer, which is not stable. If it was Ruby only it would work.